# Why is there two implementations of ref in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

There are two variants of ref usage in react:

**ref object**:

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <input ref={ref} />
}
```

and **callback ref**:

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <input ref={el => { ref.current = el; }} />
}
```

What is the need to have two ref implementations? Is this some kind of legacy issue or anything else?

Comment: No, the callback ref isn't legacy (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41468526/5648954) on why it might be useful), also see this example from the docs on [managing a list of refs](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback) on another way it could be useful.

Comment: callback is invoked whenever the ref is attached or detached